I get an error with requests only when using venv
It was working fine until yesterday, but suddenly it's not working.
When using virtualenv, I get an error when using requests to make a response.
When using the global Python, it works fine.
Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?
i'm use vscode.

global python version == venv python version



global python use >> response ok



venv python use >> error


import requests
import json

class autoHeader:
     
    def config_header(self,word='desk', set='total', fo_set='false'):
        
        self.headers ={'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cookie': 'sus_val=+hOnjgRaoDeuMuY0GFHfPO9/; NAC=wxGHBMw5zt0g; spage_uid=; NNB=R7LQEAL23SIWM; SHP_BUCKET_ID=6; NACT=1; BUC=nw_DCRSKKuSAYoxVg2wJ7FrmnI3LlRG7azkWhKn77x4=; nid_inf=297233988; NID_AUT=rt7S2AiRg6o3DL0v/GkH59GF3g+QPqdpq9ZFBSm0XLpHyOXIEcPAq2pqQL+e3zH1; NID_SES=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; NID_JKL=HgUawWfvuhWPjU1bDuHUsen68pvy9IFOQi+oxA7gRqw=', 'Origin': 'https://search.shopping.naver.com', 'Referer': 'https://search.shopping.naver.com/search/all?query=%EC%BD%9C%EB%9D%BC', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/126.0.0.0', 'sbth': 'eab715213d5e742d5bde84c0daf5ef2b350153f4364a4152f029c85f8a26052079a34f1579c0ed5e7ee978a6278c296b', 'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Microsoft Edge";v="126"', 'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"x86"', 'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"', 'sec-ch-ua-form-factors': '"Desktop"', 'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Not/A)Brand";v="8.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="126.0.6478.127", "Microsoft Edge";v="126.0.2592.87"', 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 'sec-ch-ua-model': '""', 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"', 'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"', 'sec-ch-ua-wow64': '?0'}
        
        self.params = {
            'adQuery': word,
            'eq': '',
            'iq': '',
            'fo':fo_set,
            'origQuery': word,
            'pagingIndex': '1',
            'pagingSize': '40',
            'productSet': set,
            'query': word,
            'sort': 'rel',
            'viewType': 'list',
            'window': '',
            'xq': '',
        }
        
def main():
    auto = autoHeader()
    keyword ="desk"

    auto.config_header(word=keyword,set='checkout',fo_set="true")

    response = requests.get('https://search.shopping.naver.com/api/search/all', params=auto.params, headers=auto.headers)
    print(f'response = {response.status_code}')
 
    data = response.json()

    print(type(data))
    
    temp = json.dumps(data,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
    
    # # saveFile
    with open('deskTest.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(temp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

python uninstall, install,
pip uninstall, install,
requests uninstall, install .....

You forgot to account for the HTTP 418 response

Code 418 is a joke. You might have triggered some strange server code for an unknown reason.

global python use >>> response = 200
only venv python use >> response = 418

@ahhu I am able to replicate your problem in both "global" and virtual environments. Your attempted hack of the header data is seriously flawed. You can't expect response.json() to return anything meaningful when the HTTP status code indicates a problem

It works fine when using the global Python.

@SIGHUP What should I do then


Ensure the 'requests' installed in venv by following command


pip list | grep requests

if not installed then install use

pip install requests


recreate the virtual environment sometimes solve the issues caused by misconfigured environments try the following for do


deactivate
rm -rf venv
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install requests

try this methods will work

i'm window user.
and
I have tried reinstalling multiple times
